# Force Chrome to run each tab as a process

Tags: macos, command-line, google-chrome, process, tabs

Chrome is running all of it's tabs in a single process, and when I open a large number of tabs it really slows down my machine. Considering Chrome's original marketing played up running each tab as a single process, I was surprised to find out that Chrome no longer does this.

I tried the `--proccess-per-tab` flag, but I got an error  (`-43` to be exact).

The argument I tried was

```
open -a /Applications/Google_Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google_Chrome --args --process-per-tab
```

Running Mac OS 10.6.7 and Chrome 13.0.761.0

Update: Just opened chrome, and its grouping my tabs into 4 different processes.

[image: tab list]

As time goes on, the processes will merge into one.

Comment: Check about:memory in Google Chrome and open various tabs and see if it really lumps all the processes into one.

Answer (score 7):

You should usually `open` an application bundle, not the actual binary within. So I suggest you use:

```
open -a "Google Chrome" --args --process-per-tab

open -a "/Applications/Google Chrome.app" --args --process-per-tab
```

---

Nevertheless, I cannot reproduce the issue with either Chrome 11, 12 (beta) or 13 (dev).

Activity Monitor output when using Chrome 13.0.761.0 dev, launched as `open -a "/Users/danielbeck/Applications/Google Chrome 13.app" --args --process-per-tab`:

[image]

---

After demonstrating that there's no issue with Chrome, **here's what you did wrong**:

You simply specified the wrong path. There are no underscores, only spaces, escaped by a leading `\` or wrapped in quotation marks.

> Wrong: `open -a /Applications/Google_Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google_Chrome --args --process-per-tab`
>   Right: `open -a /Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome --args --process-per-tab`
>   Alternative: `open -a "/Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome" --args --process-per-tab`

For future reference: Tab-completion properly escapes spaces. You should be able to type `/A[tab]Goo[tab][tab]Ma[tab][tab]` and it'll work.

Comment: I'm not going to remove the useless stuff at the beginning, as it took me long enough to figure out the real cause of the problem: PEBCAK.

Answer (score 1):

I have noticed that Chrome shares processes when you right click on a URL and click "Open in new Window" instead of using a new tab.